# Resolve "permission denied" when executing .sh files on WSL 2 via windows explorer

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using [this method](https://superuser.com/a/1260529) to have .sh files in Windows Explorer execute using bash.exe:

`"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c " \"./$(grep -oE '[^\\]+$' <<< '%L')\"; cd ~; bash;"`

This works fine for files outside of my WSL2 linux distro, however for files such as `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\davidg\example.sh` I get `Permission denied`.

From powershell I can run `bash.exe ./example.sh` from the working directory and it executes no problem.

Why is this happening and how can I resolve it?

**UPDATE:**
Workaround is to run `pushd \\wsl$\Ubuntu` from `cmd.exe` and execute the .sh files from the mapped drive in Windows Explorer instead of the UNC path.

Comment: What do you want to do with the first command? What is the "working directory" here?

Comment: @Biswapriyo That's added to the requisite regedit key (see link from OP). `%L` I believe is the full path to the target so that command extracts the filename and prepends `./`. The working directory ends up being the directory of the target .sh file ie `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\davidg\` in this example.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work, though I'm not entirely sure why:

`"C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe" -c "bash \"./$(grep -oE '[^\\]+$' <<< '%L')\"; cd ~; bash;"`

From what I can tell the outer call to bash is necessary to be called with `-c`, since there's a sequence of commands. Making the call to the .sh file benefited from an inner bash call with no command line options (ie passing only a reference to a file with shell commands per the manpage).

Comment: Why? How? Please insert it into your answer.